# HTML form submission in Opera

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, opera

The HTML form shown below does not work as expected in Opera (Version: 9.52). The form does not have an onsubmit attribute nor does it have an input element with type=submit. It just has two input elements of type=button and both of them onclick calls a js method where I want the user to confirm the submission. If I remove the confirm() call, it works perfectly fine. And in all other browsers (FF2, FF3, IE7) it is working fine.

Any pointers ?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function userSubmit(submitStatus)
{
    // Omitted code that uses the parameter 'submitStatus' for brevity
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?'))
        document.qpaper.pStatus.value = something;
    else
        return;     
    document.qpaper.submit();
}
</script>
<form  name = "qpaper" method = "post" action = "evaluate.page">
    <input name = "inp1" type = "button" value = "Do This" class = "formbutton" onClick = "userSubmit(false)">
    <input name = "inp2" type = "button" value = "Do That" class = "formbutton" onClick = "userSubmit(true)">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you still get prompted ? with the confirm

Comment: Yes, I get the prompt. And nothing happens when I give OK.

Answer (score 2):

1. Never use `document.nameofsomething`. It's an outdated technique that has patchy support in 21st century browsers. For forms use `document.forms.nameofform`.
2. Don't use onclick on buttons unless you need Javascript to behave differently depending on which button was pressed. If you just want to validate form or confirm submission, then use `<form onsubmit>` instead.

   ```
   <form onsubmit="return confirm('Sure?')">
   ```

   And this way you don't even need `form.submit()`. If `<form onsubmit>` returns false, submission will be aborted.
3. You don't even need to find that form.
   In `<button onclick>` form will be `this.form`.
   In `<form onsubmit>` form will be in `this` variable.

Comment: @porneL: Thanks for the tips. Regarding your second point, I am using onclick events only because I want the behavior to be different depending on the button that is pressed. I omitted the code that uses the parameter passed to the JavaScript function for brevity.